# rsyslog does not foward mail authentication records to remote server

Tags: rsyslog

rsyslog forwards auth.log sshd login records to a remote server but not mail authentication attempt records (dovecot:auth) or sudo command records.  All mail.log records are forwarded as expected.

10-rsyslog.conf contains entries for both mail and auth logs files:

```
mail.* @@hostname:514
auth.* @@hostname:514
```

Noticed that postfix mail.log records appear in the /var/log/syslog file but not the auth.log records.

Is there a separate configuration setting to forward mail server authentication attempt/failure and sudo command records?